# Estimate gas per line of code while typing

Tags: solidity, gas

Is it possible and, if yes, does a solidity editor exist that estimates gas per line of code while typing? I haven't found anything like that as yet. Either it is difficult or simply nobody has bothered to build such a tool yet.

Comment: you are going to want to test your code anyways, and you can get gas costs when doing that.  Which is going to vary by input anyways.  It takes minutes to get up and running with truffle to write unit tests...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it exists for solidity because you can write solidity over multiple lines and its not an issue.  The gas fees come once its compiled.  remix has gas estimates for each function and the actual gas fee of each operation is outlined in the yellow paper: http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf.

Comment: remix does the job!